# How to soft-commit in Sunspot (Solr 4)?

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr, rsolr

Sunspot.commit will do hard-commit. How can I issue a soft-commit command against the Solr 4 server?
Soft commits are less expensive and they make use of the NRT feature of Solr 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find soft commits feature in sunspot. I have added this functionality and created a [pull request](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/pull/614) against the sunspot main repository.